# Table with Check boxes, Data and Action Buttons. - Disable and Enable buttons based on Selection - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an application written in ASP.NET MVC5, I have A table it consists of checkboxes, text and action buttons, so each item in the table has its own action button called `.table-btn`. I would like to have it so that if I select more than one checkbox, then the entire column of the action buttons given a class of `.table-btn` disabled. Then a second button called `#second-verify-btn` is enabled.

So far I have it working so that if I select more than 2 checkboxes the `#second-verify-btn` is enabled.

```
$('#second-verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $(".individual").on("click", function () {
        if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
            $('#second-verify-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        }
        else {
            $('#second-verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: As I can understand, you are not able to disable action buttons. So first, `id` of any element should be unique hence you should give a class to your buttons instead of common `id` to all and then disable them. If more than one element has same `id` then the first result would be taken into account.

Comment: Okay, I have added a class to my buttons that are in my table columns.

Comment: Is it working as expected now?

Comment: It works as expected, however, do you know how I could load it using an AJAX call-back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work with the following code:

```
$('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        $(".individual").on("click", function () {
            if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
                $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else {
                $('.table-btn').prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using class insted of id.

Try :

```
$(".individual").on("click", function () {
    if ($(".individual:checked").length > 1) {
       $(this).closest('.second-verify-btn').prop('disabled', false);
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('.second-verify-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```